# Node.js Express - How do I compile Stylus .styl files into CSS

Tags: node.js, express, stylus

I'm trying to build an application starting from Balloons (http://balloons.io), which uses Backbone.js and express to setup the UI. I've never used these frameworks, and I'm having a hard time actually making changes.

As I understand it, .styl files are compiled into CSS files. How do I do this compilation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For production systems you'd use a [stylus executable](http://learnboost.github.com/stylus/docs/executable.html) to convert `.styl` to `.css` before deployment. It's as easy as doing:

```
stylus css --out stylesheet_dir
```

in the folder where your `.styl` files reside.

For development you can use [stylus middleware](http://learnboost.github.com/stylus/docs/middleware.html) to convert files on the fly.

Comment: Would you expect that the stylus commands would be executed as part of backbone boilerplate? I thought that running "bbb release" all this stuff would happen behind the scenes.