# How do you make use of .styl stylesheets (as opposed to .css)

Tags: css, npm, sass, ag-grid

Hopefully this isn't a stupid question as I cannot find jack after 30 minutes of Googling and forum-crawling

I got this npm package (ag-grid) and all their documentation refers to .css files but the package has only .styl files. I've never encountered .styl files and the 'net references them sparsely as some kind of css scripting language.

How can I either **a)** use these like I would a .css or **b)** easily convert them to .css?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13225447/2887133

Answer (score 2):

`.styl` files are for a CSS pre-processing language called Stylus. Stylus makes it easier to write large amounts of CSS (Just like `LESS` and `SCSS`/`SASS` if you have seen those before).

You can compile `.styl` into plain old `.css` through [task runners](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-stylus), node and even a GUI application.

- This post describes more of the automation through node: [Setting up auto compile for stylus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10995330/setting-up-auto-compile-for-stylus)
- Alternatively, you could manually compile it once and use them in your project (if you don't intend on changing the CSS). http://stylus-lang.com/#get-styling-with-stylus
- Or if you desire you could even use a GUI to manage these sort of files such as [PrePros](https://prepros.io/), a free and easy to use tool for compiling CSS (and much more!) that requires preprocessing.